# Search filter in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am new to Angular 2. I am trying out the search filter function using the Pipe. However, I am unable to actually search for an item. I have been watching videos on how to search with filter, but they proved to be futile. Would appreciate if any of you can help me out here.

HTML File:

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
  </h1>
 </div>



 <form id="filter">
<label>Filter car by parts:</label>
<input type="text" ng-Model="term"/>
</form>
<ul id="car-listing">
<li *ngFor ="let carPart of carParts | filter:term">
 <h2> {{carPart.name | uppercase}} </h2>
 <p> {{carPart.description}} </p>
 <p *ngIf="carPart.inStock > 5"> {{carPart.inStock}} in Stock </p>
 <p *ngIf="carPart.inStock === 0"> Stock running low </p>
 <p> {{carPart.price | currency:'USD'}} </p>
 <p *ngIf="carPart.price === 350"> Special Promotion Only </p>



</li>

</ul>
```

Typescript File:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FilterPipe} from './filter.pipe';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'List of Car Parts';
  
   carParts =  [ {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Regular Tires",
   "description": "Tires for city use",
   "inStock": 10,
   "price": 200,
 
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Supreme Tires",
   "description": "Tires for all conditions",
   "inStock": 0,
   "price": 350,
  
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "name": "Premium Tires",
   "description": "Tires for all luxury models",
   "inStock": 8,
   "price": 400,
 
 } ];

}
```

filter.pipe.ts

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(carParts: any, term: any): any {
    if (term === undefined) return carParts;
 
 return carParts.filter(function(carPart){
  return carPart.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
  })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ngModel incorrectly.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term"/>
```

please check https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Hope it helps!!